# Generate pop-up window to select object in Grails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I am trying to piece together the following work flow:

- The user clicks the "New Field Trip Request" button

  - This renders the create view which contains the form template, which itself contains an "Add Location" button
- The user clicks the "Add Location" button

  - This pops up a window with a list of possible locations which the user can select
- The user selects a location

  - This dynamically refreshes the field trip form, which now contains the address of the location

Is this possible? I believe that this is with Ajax, but I have no experience with Ajax so I could be way off base. Some pseudo-code of how I envision this working is:

```
<!-- create.gsp -->
<g:form controller="fieldTrip" id="${user.id}">  
  <g:render template="form" />
  <g:actionSubmit value="Save" action="save" />
</g:form>
```

The form then contains

```
<h2>Location Information</h2>

<!-- Make this an Ajax button which pops up a new window -->
<g:link controller="location" action="index"><g:actionSubmit value="Select Location" /></g:link>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="address">
        <g:message code="location.address.label" default="Address" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="address">
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'address', 'error')} required">
        <g:textField name="address" value="${locationInstance?.address}" disabled="${true}"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="city">
        <g:message code="location.city.label" default="City" />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="state">
        <g:message code="location.state.label" default="State" />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="zip">
        <g:message code="location.zip.label" default="Zip" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'city', 'error')} required">
        <g:textField name="city" value="${locationInstance?.city}" disabled="${true}"/>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'state', 'error')}">
        <g:select name="state" value="${locationInstance?.state?.id}" from="${isec.State.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="${{it.name}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${true}"/>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: locationInstance, field: 'zip', 'error')}">
        <g:textField name="zip" value="${locationInstance?.zip}" disabled="${true}"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="startDate">
        <g:message code="fieldTripInstance.startDate.label" default="Start Date" />
        <g:if test="${disabled == 'false'}">
          <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </g:if>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="endDate">
        <g:message code="fieldTripInstance.endDate.label" default="End Date" />
        <g:if test="${disabled == 'false'}">
          <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </g:if>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: fieldTripInstance, field: 'startDate', 'error')} required">
        <g:textField class="datepicker" name="startDate" value="${fieldTripInstance?.startDate?.format('MM/dd/yyyy')}" disabled="${disabled}" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: fieldTripInstance, field: 'endDate', 'error')} required">
        <g:textField class="datepicker" name="endDate" value="${fieldTripInstance?.endDate?.format('MM/dd/yyyy')}" disabled="${disabled}" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="purpose">
        <g:message code="fieldTripInstance.purpose.label" default="Purpose" />
        <g:if test="${disabled == 'false'}">
          <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </g:if>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: fieldTripInstance, field: 'purpose', 'error')} required">
        <g:textArea name="purpose" value="${fieldTripInstance?.purpose}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="notes">
        <g:message code="fieldTripInstance.notes.label" default="Notes" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><g:textArea name="notes" value="${fieldTripInstance?.notes}" disabled="${disabled}"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How would I start to do this with Ajax?

Comment: I would break down your process and question into small chunks - 'Pop up a window with a list of locations', 'Dynamically refresh the form', etc.  These small chunks may have already been asked/answers and they make better questions to begin with.  jQuery has the ability to do Ajax and manipulate the DOM (dynamically show a modal) so this is definitely possible.